# Why don't custom upstart job names tab complete in the service command?

Tags: bash, upstart

I'm used to create upstart services with a file in `/etc/init/<service>.conf` and it works perfectly fine, the only thing I'd like to is to have tab completion the same way that every service in /etc/init.d/ have right now.

When writing sudo service xx the name of the service should apear.

Is there a way to add upstart services to that autocompletion list?

Comment: Hi , have you tried before ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Every package that provides a standard daemon using upstart is required to provide a symlink in `/etc/init.d` by Debian policy. So autocompletion for `sudo service name` already works. Make sure that you have the `bash-completion` package installed if you're having problems.

If you are creating your own upstart jobs, then symlink `/etc/init.d/your_job` to `/lib/init/upstart-job` like the other upstart jobs are doing already. This will make your own jobs work the same way.

There are special upstart jobs in `/etc/init` that do not have a corresponding entry in `/etc/init.d`. These are an exception. From Debian Policy:

> An exception to this rule is scripts or jobs provided by the init implementation itself; such jobs may be required for an implementation-specific equivalent of the /etc/rcS.d/ scripts and may not have a one-to-one correspondence with the init scripts.

These exceptions do not currently work with `bash-completion`. However, you can use `start`, `stop`, `restart` and `reload` directly without `service`, and autocompletion will work. For example, `sudo start shut` correctly autocompletes. But you shouldn't normally need to directly call upstart jobs that do not have a corresponding `init.d` entry.

Note: I tested this on Saucy. If support doesn't appear in an older release, perhaps it is not available there (but you'll get it soon when you upgrade to a sufficiently new release).

Comment: The bug on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/1188897